# Google sign in with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, google-signin

I'm implementing Google sign in for my Xamarin app, by following [this article](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in). Which nuget package contains the `GoogleSignIn` object?

Answer (score 0):

Before you are able to work using these APIs and you will use WebView but you will get an Authentication error, disallowed_useragent.
Look at this article: 
https://medium.com/@didourebai/authentication-with-google-using-xamarin-forms-403-thats-an-error-disallowed-useragent-fcaadad6f01a

And the solution is to use Xamarin.Auth 
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth